# subplots in python with multiple line charts using pandas ans seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, plotly-python

I have a data frame as shown below

```
product    bought_date     Monthly_profit     Average_discout
A          2016            85000000           5
A          2017            55000000           5.6
A          2018            45000000           10
A          2019            35000000           9.8
B          2016            75000000           5
B          2017            55000000           4.6
B          2018            75000000           11
B          2019            45000000           9.8
C          2016            95000000           5.3
C          2017            55000000           5.1
C          2018            50000000           10.2
C          2019            45000000           9.8
```

From the above I would like to plot 3 subplots.

one for product A, B and C.

In each subplot there should be 3 line plot, where

```
X axis = bought_date
Y axis1 = Monthly_profit
Y axis2 = Average_discout
```

I tried below code.

```
sns.set(style = 'darkgrid')
sns.lineplot(x = 'bought_date', y  = 'Monthly_profit', style = 'product', 
             data = df1, markers = True, ci = 68, err_style='bars')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant 1: using subplots and separating the data manually

```
products = df['product'].unique()
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,len(products),figsize=(20,10))
for i,p in enumerate(products):
    sns.lineplot('bought_date', 'Monthly_profit', data=df[df['product']==p], ax=ax[i])
    sns.lineplot('bought_date', 'Average_discout', data=df[df['product']==p], ax=ax[i].twinx(), color='orange')
    ax[i].legend([f'Product {p}'])
```

Variant 2: using [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html):

```
def lineplot2(x, y, y2, **kwargs):
    ax = sns.lineplot(x, y, **kwargs)
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    sns.lineplot(x, y2, ax=ax2, **kwargs)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='product')
g.map(lineplot2, 'bought_date', 'Monthly_profit', 'Average_discout', marker='o')
```

These are just general rough examples, you'll have to tidy up axis labels etc. as needed.

Comment: Can we add legend for each line plot

Comment: `ax[i].legend([f'Product {p}'])`

Comment: in which line, pls help me in increasing the size this plot.